# Download file that we have browse using input type file multiple - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, input-type-file

I have code that you can input multiple file using input type file multiple, which is a basic html5.

When **you click the input file**, you browse the file that you want (can be multiple), **it will show you the list of files that you have input with remove button for each item**, so you can remove it for each item.

Now the problem is I want to **enhance it with download button**.

***Anybody knows how to add download file from input type file function using javascript ?***

Thank you so much

Comment: Since the files are already in users machine what is the need to download them again?

Comment: Yeah I know but you know client is a king such a common problem right ? It makes me crazy.